# How does this converges? Sequence and series convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider the following  problem-

Converges or Diverges? $$(1-2)-(1-2^{1/2})+(1-2^{1/3})-(1-2^{1/4})+....$$

I said it converges but then my work I showed in paper got wrong

How would you prove that it is converges?

Comment: Check the conditions for which an alternating series converges and check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758112/sequence-and-series-of-convergence-problem

Comment: Use telescoping series.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=1-2^{1/n}$. Clearly
$$\eqalign{a_n&=1-\exp\left(\frac{\ln 2}{n}\right)=1-\left(1-\frac{\ln 2}{n}+{\cal O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\cr
&=\frac{\ln 2}{n}+{\cal O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}$$
Now, the series $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is convergent, and by the observation above
the series $\sum(-1)^n(a_n-\frac{\ln2}{n})$ is absolutely convergent.

Thus
$\sum(-1)^n a_n$ is convergent, being the sum of two convergent series, and we are done. 
$\qquad\square$